# How to disable message in webform "Changes you made may not be saved."?

Tags: webforms

I have a message from the webform module "Changes you made may not be saved." which I do not want to see anymore. I get it on any form.

I try to disable this form. Therefore I added a js to the theme. In the hook_form_alter I add this js script to form attached

The JS file looks like this:

```
(function ($) {

    $(this).click(function() { window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: There's no exposed option to disable it, you'll have to either monkey-patch it in your own JS, or implement `hook_js_alter` to remove the offending script (webform/js/webform.form.unsaved.js)

Comment: thxs see updated question

Comment: Hi @clive some ideeas?